# Не получается подключить Mysql к VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Нужно подключить Mysql к VS 2012, но выдаёт ошибку
Подскажите, как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не студию к Mysql должны подключить, а в проект вашего будущего приложения установить необходимый пакет. Для установки следует использовать менеджер NuGET пакетов или открыть консоль пакетного менеджера и в нем дать команду `Install-Package MySql.Data`

Comment: подскажите, как открыть эту консоль?

Comment: Я не использую русский интерфейс в студии, но у меня это так View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console. Или правый клик по названию проекта и выберите менеджер пакетов

Comment: нашёл, выдало ошибку Недопустимая команда "Install".

Comment: скопируйте команду из первого коммента

Comment: так и сделал---

Comment: А строка в консоли начинается на `PM>`   ?

Comment: получилось, вот Install-Package : Схема версии "Google.Protobuf" несовместима с версией 2.0.30625.9003 в NuGet. Обновите NuGet до последней 
версии, расположенной по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
строка:1 знак:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  MySql.Data
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: у вас устаревшая версия студии и пакетного менеджера, попробуйте сходить по ссылке,кот. в ошибке и обновить менеджер, а потом попробуйте снова. Или обновите наконец студию до последней версии.

Comment: а синтаксис для .net в 17 версии (сильно) отличается от 12?

Comment: нет не отличается, всегда есть обратная совместимость, т.е. добавляется новое, но старое остается рабочим

Comment: спасибо большое за информацию :) .net не изучаю, но для курсача надо :d

Comment: У "MySql.Data" уже есть зависимость, определенная для "Google.Protobuf" теперь такая ошибка

Comment: помогло установить версию 6.9.12 для mysql